# I cannot read a property that I just set in my object. Why?

Tags: .net, moq

I'm using Moq. The example is pretty simple. I cannot read a property after I set it.

```
var mock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
mock.Setup(x => x.Headers).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
var response = mock.Object;

// now I set StatusCode
response.StatusCode = 404;

// now I try to read, but StatusCode is 0 here, not 404
var statusCode = response.StatusCode
```

As you can see, I'm not specifying any special behavior for `StatusCode`. what do I have to do so that it will allow me to write and read it?

Answer (score 1):

It's because, in order to make a property to act like a normal property, you should call the method `SetupProperty` on it.

```
mock.SetupProperty(x => x.StatusCode);
```